# Add a confirmation before moving comments to a chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, confirmation

When a comment chain is too long, new comments have to be loaded through the `add / show 1 more comments` link. After clicking on this link, I can add a reply:

[image: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?]

After quickly **mis**clicking on the textarea, a new chat is created. Without any confirmation...

---

I've experienced this [at least three times][2]. Can a confirmation dialog be added, so that chatrooms cannot be created by accident?

Comment: Better yet, can users just have the ability to turn that feature off altogether if they don't wish to participate in chat? That would even prevent *other* people from inviting them to chat.

Comment: @CodyGray That's an easy thing to do: Create a User Stylesheet, e.g using Stylish, and add the following line: `@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {.discussion-info{display:none;}}`. You will never see that thing again.

Comment: @RobW But others could still invite you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have been using this [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) sheet for a while, without any issues:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain('stackoverflow.com'),
               domain('stackexchange.com'),
               domain('superuser.com'),
               domain('serverfault.com'),
               domain('stackapps.com'),
               domain('askubuntu.com') {
    .discussion-info { /* Hide move to chat "feature" */
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This can be implemented in a UserScript/GreaseMonkey/Chrome extension using (Click [here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) for help on installing an User Script. Generally, open your text editor, paste the code below in it, and save the file with a **`.user.js`** extension. Then open the file in your browser):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Stack Exchange: Get rid of move-to-chat suggestion
// @namespace      Rob W
// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match          http://superuser.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.superuser.com/questions/*
// @match          http://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match          http://askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match          http://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match          http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/*
// @match          https://stackapps.com/questions/*
// @author         Rob W
// @version        1.0
// @run-at         document-end
// ==/UserScript==

var s = document.createElement('style');
s.appendChild(s.createTextNode('.discussion-info{display:none;}'));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 7):

I was about to propose the same thing having just done this myself twice in a row.

Blame me for being clumsy, etc, but while it sounds trivial, when it does happen you have to:

- Be redirected and wait for chat to load
- Close it all down
- Get back to the question and remove the comment linking to chat

As this tends to happen in "quick fire" comments, the other person likely sees the chat comment while you are being sent to chat and having to close it down. So they think you want chat, and might even have already clicked the link.

It's not a very *frequent* issue, but I would imagine the code to make it happen can't be too much work?

---

RobW's suggestion sounds great, but I don't use "*UserScript/GreaseMonkey/Chrome extension*", and this is not something implemented into the site.

Using the site I don't really want to have to use 3rd party plugins for a better UX (within reason, of course).

Comment: yeah, happened to me twice too, though not in a row.

Comment: 4th time for me now... Getting annoying!

Answer (score -4):

It's fair to argue that a single click shouldn't trigger an irreversible action.

Alternate proposal: automatically create the chatroom without any clicks at all, copy the conversation there, show the participants the link, and block them from posting any more comments for a day.

Comment: Anyway, I disagree. Sometimes people are just not interested in chat. Forcing them into it is a bad idea in my opinion and will only antagonise them, leading to both confusion and frustration.

Comment: Arguably, this only triggers when you're *already* chatting @Shadow - the fact that you're using comments to do so is a minor detail, and it is possible that such conversations could be drawn into their own threads with less disruption than currently exists today.

Comment: IMO this means punishing people for using a feature of the site. Want to prevent it? Limit comments to e.g. 3 per user per post. After the limit is reached, the user will see "Please use chat for further discussion of this post"

Comment: You're proposing a much more strict limit without an alternative. I fail to see how that solves anything.

Comment: It doesn't solve anything, but not forcing people to use chat just directs them towards it. If one wants it, he/she will take the required actions on their own. (I'm talking about the "automatically create the chatroom without any clicks at all" part in your answer)

Comment: So instead of offering a fast path to folks who are already... Chatting... You would have them blocked and hand-waved in the direction of a system they may have never seen... On the off-chance that they might not like it.

Comment: Well, I know chat. I use chat a lot. And still highly dislike it when a whole chat room is created when I never intended it. So yes, I assume based on that that many others will dislike it even more. I might be wrong of course. :)

Comment: Then you have no use for this feature, confirmation or otherwise @ShadowWizard. Cody's "I never want to chat" checkbox is really the only solution that'd meet your needs here.

Comment: lol, and ironically enough we started chatting here... but since we kind of hit a dead end, I don't think there's a point in continuing this in a chat room.