# Poor location of "Would you like to move this discussion to chat?"

Tags: feature-request, comments

When I click on "add comment" and the comment box appears, I click on the comment box to set its focus and begin typing.

This is a long ingrained habit, either borne from experience on previous websites or possibly on this website of earlier versions didn't automatically move focus. (I don't know which)

Unfortunately, when the software decides to suggest chat, it moves the comment box down two lines and puts part of the link *exactly* where the top-left corner of the comment box *normally* appears. Nearly 100% of the time this happens, I accidentally click on it, and I have to reload the page, reexpand comments, delete the comment suggesting a move to chat, and click on add comment again before I can start entering my comment. (and hope I don't reflexively click the link a second time, which I have done!)

Would it be possible to add a preference to prevent these suggestions from appearing? Or would it be possible to move the link off to the right side?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121954/152859

Comment: +1. This happens to me all the time, too.

Comment: It's almost as if we're discouraging extended discussion in comments.

Comment: @Telthien Shog9 has taught you well, young one.

Comment: @Telthien ...by adding a UX bug?