# Editing a question from the close queue and not editing anything marks the review as completed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, edits, vote-to-close

Someone started to close [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327056/can-we-rescue-the-information-in-this-question-somehow) as "not reproducible" on MSO. I found it frankly moronic since it's an ongoing discussion (and the moderator notice makes this painfully obvious), so I decided to [kick it out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151443/213575) [clicking "edit"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/10964) before robo-reviewers (yes, there are on meta) close the question. Something unexpected happened. The question was de-queued but there's no revision created for my edition. Granted that I didn't really edit anything so that was kind of *obvious* to happen, but funnily the review let my not-really-a-edit count as "edit" review and completed it.

I'm still not convinced that "edit" should dequeue review from the close queue, as anecdotal experience tells me that people don't actually fix problems and since these do not ["get bumped by the edit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162058/213575), it's ripe for abuse.

Comment: Related, similar problem with [improving suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/i-improved-an-edit-but-did-i-actually).

Comment: reproduced, looking into that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. This will be fixed in all review actions that allow editing a post. After the next build rolls out (build rev `2016.6.30.4694` on MSE/MSO, `2016.6.30.3718` on sites), you will get this validation error instead in review queues:

[image]

Comment: But I am asking about posting comments, not reviews.

Comment: How did this answer *move* from [one question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280714/why-does-pressing-enter-on-some-sites-posts-the-comment-while-on-other-sites-it) to another?

Comment: Despite weirdness does it warrant a low quality flag?

Comment: @Glorfindel employees can move answers around. I accidentally posted the answer on the wrong question (lots of open tabs with bugs here), so I used the opportunity to test another [bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280579/questions-last-activity-timestamp-is-not-updated-with-a-new-answer/280660#280660) ....