# Why does pressing enter on some sites posts the comment, while on other sites it adds a new line?

Tags: support, comments

So today I was on [Chinese Language](//chinese.stackexchange.com/) and was posting a comment. After writing the comment, I pressed enter to post. However, a new line is inserted:

> [image: new line added]

Then I went to Stack Overflow and posted a comment. This time, pressing enter did not add a new line. It did not add a new line on User Experience either.

Why? Bug?

Comment: I've always seen an "enter" insert a comment when I'm on a desktop computer, and insert a new line when I'm on mobile.

Comment: Reproduced on [chinese.se] on Chrome for Windows. I think that's the first site on PC that I had this experience.

Comment: This is a per site setting. Sites can ask in their meta to disable Enter from submitting comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What if this can be reproduced in lots of sites?

Comment: I am sure there was an answer just half an hour ago. Where did it go? I can't see it with 10K tools...

Comment: @Pat http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5054464#5054464

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each site can ask to disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> from submitting comments.

For example [Chinese Language SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/) asked it here: [Disable [Enter] in comment field](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/disable-enter-in-comment-field) and it was indeed done, two years ago.

This is the reason given there:

> My IME allows me to choose from several hanzi and commits the selected hanzi by typing [Enter]. At the moment I have to edit the comment for every hanzi I enter (which also means I can write a comment for at most 5 minutes).

Which does make sense. So I'd say that any language-specific site has a high chance of disabling <kbd>Enter</kbd> from submitting comments for that reason.

More sites where <kbd>Enter</kbd> is disabled from submitting: (Feel free to add more)

- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments)

Comment: Oh I see! My IME doesn't do that though.

Comment: Although now that they've [fiddled with it](http://www.stum.de/2016/06/24/handling-ime-events-in-javascript/) I wonder if this is still necessary?

Comment: @Tim interesting, I wasn't really aware of that.

Comment: It's no longer necessary. We just forgot that submit on Enter was disabled on Chinese.SE as well. Will adjust.

Comment: The new setting is now active network-wide: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280734/improved-ime-handling