# Improved IME Handling is now active

Tags: discussion, comments, feedback

In the past there was an issue (reported for example [on the Japanese Language Meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments)) where pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select an IME suggestion would also submit the comment.

The good news is that we believe to have found the proper way to handle this, allowing you to use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select your IME suggestion, while also still being able to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the comment if you're not in the middle of composing a word.

This change is now active on all Stack Exchange network sites.

I've [written a blog post](http://www.stum.de/2016/06/24/handling-ime-events-in-javascript/) with the technical details of this change.

Comment: Weird.  Your website is blocked by my company's crappy firewall (it's a [Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx) box, but seriously, screw those guys).  Says it's a "Malicious Site".  Sounds like my kinda website, actually.

Comment: @Won't Thanks for the heads-up. I guess it's forbidden knowledge. Archived it: http://web.archive.org/web/20160630183843/http://www.stum.de/2016/06/24/handling-ime-events-in-javascript/

Comment: @MichaelStum It doesn't appear to be in effect on some meta sites (such as Stack Overflow Meta). Was this intentional or were some sites just missed?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder It works fine on Mac OS X for me. Testing with Win10 next, it seems the Anniversary Update made some changes, not sure if related. What's your OS and Browser, and do you see it on all sites? (The new IME is no longer a site specific option but part of the baseline code, so it should work or not work on all sites)

Comment: It does not work for me today on Linux (Linux Mint 20.3; fcitx/mozc; Firefox 110 although it has not worked on previous versions for quite some time).