# Comments disappearing for no reason

Tags: support, comments

I recently posted my first question on a Stack Exchange website. Someone responded in the comments, and I responded back. However, after a few minutes, some of the person's comments disappeared! Why? Is this a bug?

I just noticed that the comments that disappeared were the first **4** written to me by **one** specific person.

Moreover, after in total we wrote about 10 comments, a notification appeared saying something like "Do you want to automatically add this to the chat?" I clicked on it, yet nothing seemed to happen. What does that do?

So how do I get the notification back to "re-get" that chat link page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Users can delete their own comments and moderators can delete comments that they believe are rude, non-constructive or off topic. Why do you think this is a bug? It's perfectly possible that the comments were simply deleted. Can you post a link to where the comments were?

Comment: Ok, I forgot that people than delete their own comments. However, it wasn't anything off-topic, rude, or non-constructive. Moreover, that doesn't answer my second question.

Comment: "Move comments to chat" doesn't actually *move* the comments... it just creates a chat room where you can continue to have your discussion... With your rep on Travel, though, I don't believe you're able to create chat rooms... I've never been certain if comment chain chat rooms were exempt from this limitation, though.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused: 1. What level (rep) would I need to create chat rooms? 2. If my rep isn't high enough, why did the notification appear in the first place?

Comment: **In general**, you need 100 rep to create a chat room. As I've said, though, there are some exceptions, so I'm not sure if this includes creating chat rooms from comment chains on questions. The link is automatically created when there are a certain number of back and forth comments between two users on one post... or when the overall number of posts hits some quantity... but the link is a bit iffy... sometimes it shows up, other times it doesn't. I don't know that it checks rep levels when it appears, though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took a look at the question.

The user who commented deleted their comments and then marked a bunch of the remaining ones as obsolete.

Given that these comments were all about the title/content of the question and were all addressed, there was no need for them to stay around and clutter the page.

---

The "Do you want to automatically add this to the chat?" message should cause a confirmation popup to come up. That would create a chat room that would contain a copy of all the comments so far and add a comment that links to that chat room.

Comment: 1. How can you tell if a comment is marked as "obsolete"?

Comment: 2. My point is that that never happened.

Comment: @user49558 - I am a developer at Stack Overflow. I have access to a lot of things :)

Comment: Is there a rep minimum to create the comment-based chat rooms?

Comment: @Catija - I believe usual chat rep limits.

Comment: So about the second thing, I don't see any comment that links to a chat room.

Comment: So, 100 rep to create a chat room or only the 20 required to use chat? The OP only has 23 rep, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't know what happened there, @user49558 - could be that you dismissed the confirmation or that something went wrong in the process.

Comment: @Catija - I would need to look at the code to see what would actually happen.

Comment: There is no confirmation dialog. I misclicked the "move comments to chat" at least three times.

Comment: @Sha - huh. I was sure there was.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121954/add-a-confirmation-before-moving-comments-to-a-chat

Comment: Shows you how often I use this bit of functionality, @Sha

Comment: Yup. Still, adding a confirmation would be mega awesome. :-)